# Connecting to database on Android using room

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, android-room

I have been looking into databases and the persistence library `Room` for allowing live updates to my android application but I am struggling to grasp how `Room` really communicates to databases. I am not sure I have the right idea of how it is meant to be used.

What I am imagining is connecting my android app to a remote database, users on the app can make changes and when those changes are pushed to the database it automatically updates all other active users data from that database. If it is relevant this is part of a google maps application I am running.

(I am not concerning myself with any security measures right now as this is just for proof of concept)

Is everything I need to do this a part of the `Room` library or are there pieces that I am missing? If so what are the recommended libraries for this. Once again the pieces that I need are this:
1. Connect to remote database
2. Pull values from database to initialize application
3. Make changes to database values from the app (admin mode)
4. Push those changes to remote database
5. Update all other active apps running on other android devices with the new changes on the database

If I am completely off point I would appreciate if someone could point me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 4):

> Is everything I need to do this a part of the Room library or are there pieces that I am missing? I

Room has nothing to do with any of that.

Room is for a local SQLite database on the device. Room has nothing to do with communicating with your Web service.

Comment: Okay thank you, I was afraid that was the case but I couldn't figure it out for sure. Since that is the case my question is pretty off point so I will delete it, but can you point me in the direction of how I should go about doing what I posted? I feel like there should be a simple library for this but I have not been able to find anything for it

Comment: @TravisHerbert: "I feel like there should be a simple library for this" -- that really depends on you consider a "remote database" to mean. You should focus first on finding a "remote database" that meets your needs, then find out what Android connectivity options exist for it. So, for example, if you settle on using a hosted GraphQL database (e.g., Graphcool), you could use Apollo-Android to interact with the GraphQL Web service endpoint. Or, you might use Retrofit for a REST Web service. Or the "remote database" might have its own Android client library.

Comment: This database server will be something I am setting up myself. I looked at some of those and I think Retrofit is what I am looking for. If i understand from my brief reading I use java interfaces (similar to room and its localdb) to create queries and I use this interface to communicate between my java objects and the database

Comment: @TravisHerbert: Retrofit is a client library for REST-style Web services. If you intend to create a REST-style Web service (backed by some database), then Retrofit is a likely candidate to use for communicating with that Web service.

Comment: Thank you for all the information, that clears up where I need to start. It is a little overwhelming jumping into database stuff for the first time so I appreciate the assistance XD

Comment: @CommonsWare, I'm confused. On their website, the Android developers specifically say: Apps that handle non-trivial amounts of structured data can benefit greatly from persisting that data locally. The most common use case is to cache relevant pieces of data. That way, when the device cannot access the network, the user can still browse that content while they are offline. Any user-initiated content changes are then synced to the server after the device is back online.

Because Room takes care of these concerns for you, we highly recommend using Room instead of SQLite.

Comment: @SDSMTKyzer: That is a poorly worded portion of their documentation. I will try to get it fixed.